# Can I prevent tilda from hiding?

Tags: linux, tilda

I have installed `tilda-0.9.6` on my Gentoo laptop and I'd like it to stay for good, not to hide. I've been forced to link it to a keyboard shortcut otherwise it wouldn't start (or would segfault).

The trouble is (I don't know why) it sometimes hides on its own the first time I run `emerge`. I don't want to fix this as if it were a bug, I just want `tilda` to stay on my desktop background without giving it the possibility to hide. Yeah, right, basically I want a drop-down terminal to forget about being drop-down and stick to my desktop background permanently instead. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either start in configuration mode:

```
tilda -C
```

And select:

```
Height:  100%
Width:   100%
Check: Set as Desktop Window
Uncheck: Always on top
```

Or, edit your `~/.config/tilda/config_0`

```
above=false
set_as_desktop=true
```

**My settings**

I run a mostly plain `openbox` and set `tilda` to run at 50% width on my 1920x1080 screen.

Here is my `openbox/autostart`:

```
$ cat ~/.config/openbox/autostart
# Programs that will automatically start when logging in.

# Set the wallpaper
# hsetroot -solid "#404040"
hsetroot -add "#101010" -add "#404040" -add "#888888" -gradient 240 &

# Display Time and Date
tdc -s 14 -c green -w 240 -f "%T  %D" &

#Desktop Terminal
tilda &
```

---

And my `tilda` configuration:

```
$ cat ~/.config/tilda/config_0
tilda_config_version="1.3.1"
...
max_width=960
max_height=1080
above=false
hidden=false
set_as_desktop=true
centered_horizontally=false
centered_vertically=false
```

And a screenshot of the GUI configuration tool:

[image]

---

**Github page**

For those who need the newest version:

[`tilda` Github](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda)

Comment: I don't see any such option «*Set as desktop window*». Note however I don't necessarily want it to cover 100% of my desktop as I have currently made it so it covers areas not covered by icons. Does that option imply 100% of the desktop surface be covered?

Comment: @Nasha : added my configuration to the answer.

Comment: I definitely don't have that layout in the configuration dialogue. A few of them don't appear: "*start full-screen*", "*set as desktop window*" and "*non-focus pull up behaviour*". Instead I have "*Audible bell*",  "*Cursor blinks*", "*enable antialiasing*", "*allow bold text*" plus tab position and font selection drop down lists. I guess yours is a different version, I don't know whether mine is newer or older though.

Comment: @Nasha : added the github page to the answer.